# Create non-quoted identifier column names when creating sql developer table in python

Tags: sql, python-3.x, pandas, oracle-sqldeveloper

After connecting to the oracle DB, I have created a sql developer table via Python, I then load my csv into the df and convert the datatypes to varchar for a faster load into the table (because the default str type takes an unreasonable amount of time). The data loads fast and it is all present, but the issue is when interrogating the data in SQL Developer, I am forced to put '' round the column names for it to be recognised, and when trying to perform simple operations on the data such as SELECT * FROM new_table ORDER BY 'CATEGORY' asc sql can not seem to sort my data at all, does anyone have any suggestions please? Below is a snippet of the python code I have used

```
os.chdir('C:\\Oracle\\instantclient_19_5')

dataload= Table('new_table, meta,
Column('Category',VARCHAR(80)),
Column('Code',VARCHAR(80)),
Column('Medium',VARCHAR(80)),
Column('Source',VARCHAR(80)),
Column('Start_date',VARCHAR(80)),
Column('End_date',VARCHAR(80))

meta.create_all(engine)

df3= pd.read_csv(fname)

dtyp = {c:types.VARCHAR(df3[c].str.len().max())
for c in df3.columns[df3.dtypes == 'object'].tolist()}
df3.to_sql(new_table, engine, index=False, if_exists='replace', dtype=dtyp)
```

Comment: SQL uses double quotes for delimited identifiers, e.g. `"CATEGORY"`.

Comment: uppercase your column/table names, don't use case sensitive object names, you're only making things harder on yourself later

Comment: To both  thank you for your responses, making all the columns uppercase in my code AND in the file itself has done the trick and negated the need to use "" around anything now, the only thing Python did not seem to like is capitalising the table name but that seems to be automatically done on the sql side. Cheers.